# php method undefined error

Tags: php

I have a Model.class.php and a Bag.class.php, the Bag class extends the Model class.

But when i try to call a function defined in Bag.class.php, it show a fatal error " Call to undefined function fill_entity() in"

bag.class.php :

```
class Bag extends Model{
 public function __construct($table_name){
    $this->table_name = $table_name;
 }

 public function fill_entity($row){
     $this->id = $row['bagID'];
     $this->name = $row['bagName'];
     $this->price = $row['bagPrice'];
     $this->url = $row['bagURL'];
     $this->img_url = $row['bagImgURL'];
     $this->mall_id = $row['mallID'];
     $this->brand_id = $row['brandID'];
 }
```

here's my php page where i call this function :

```
$bag = new Bag($bagtype);
$bag.fill_entity($row);  <---- error on this line.
```

Comment: Use `->` instead of `.` to reference the function.

Comment: ...Because what you've written is valid PHP. It attempts to concatenate the output of a non-existant global function `fill_entity()` with the variable `$bag`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax.  PHP doesn't use dot notation, but rather [`->` (arrow/pointer notation)](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19686/what-kind-of-notation-is)

Try using this:

```
$bag->fill_entity($row);
```

(The `.` is still used in PHP, but is used for [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).)

Don't feel bad about missing this, I did it plenty of times when I first tackled PHP.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, it would be `$bag->fill_entity($row);` rather than `$bag.fill_entity($row);`.